# Combine json file with CSV- similar to vlookup

Tags: python, json, bash, csv, grep

In plain terms, I'm trying to combine two sets of data. I'm open to use grep/bash or python.

1. Read directory /mediaid
2. Read the .json files' filename
3. if the .json file name matches a row in the .csv, copy the contents of the json file in that row (if not, just skip)

INPUT DATA

**File1.csv**

```
testentry, 1234
testentry1, 6789
```

INPUT DATA (the filename is the MEDIAID to check)

**1234.json**

```
[
{"id":"1", "text":"Nice man!"},
{"id":"2", "text":"Good job"}
]
```

**6789.json**

```
[
{"id":"1", "text":"Test1"},
{"id":"2", "text":"Test2"}
]
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT DATA .csv**

```
testentry, 1234, Nice man!, Good job
testentry1, 6789, Test1, Test2
```

My attempt using GREP is in progress, but I can't get the json file names to be checked and pass the data from them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

indir="$HOME/indir"
outdir="$HOME/outdir"

cd "$indir" || exit
mkdir -p "$outdir" || exit
for f in *.csv; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    lines=()
    while IFS=, read -ra cols; do
        if (( ${#cols[@]} != 2 )); then
            echo "Sorry buddy, you'll have to use a real CSV parser to handle: $f" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        # Does the basename match the contents of the first column?
        if [[ ${cols[0]} == "${f%.*}" ]]; then
            echo "Match found in $f"
        fi
        lines+=("${cols[0]},${cols[1]}")
    done <"$f"
    # something with JQ to read the json filename, and pass its data into the row
    printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" > "$outdir/$f" || exit
done
```

A failed, but slightly better attempt in Python:

```
import csv
import json

path_to_json = 'somedir/'

json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

print json_files  # 

with open(json_files) as lookuplist:
    # IT NEEDS to match the mediaID from the json FILENAME
    with open('file1.csv', "r") as csvinput:
        with open('VlookupOut','w') as output:

            reader = csv.reader(lookuplist)
            reader2 = csv.reader(csvinput)
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            d = {}
            for xl in reader2:
                d[xl[2]] = xl[3:]

            for i in reader:
                if i[4] in d:
                    i.append(d[i[4]])
                writer.writerow(i)
```

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. You want all text from the json file, regardless of the ID?

Comment: Correct- the ID is not important. It should only match according to a filename. I've updated the OP to make a bit clearer.

Comment: does your csv really have spaces after the commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This provides your required output:

```bsh
for file in /mediaid/*; do
    while read -r entry fileid; do 
        jsonfile="$fileid.json"
        if [[ -f "$jsonfile" ]]; then 
            text=$(jq -r 'map(.text) | join(", ")' "$jsonfile")
            echo "$entry $fileid, $text"
        fi
    done < "$file"
done > output.csv
```

Uses [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to parse the JSON files

Comment: That hasn't worked. It needs to join rows that already exist in a .CSV file. I'm not simply printing to a CSV file

Comment: Please explain further. I don't understand this new requirement

Comment: I am trying to combine values in the JSON file to be printined on an already populated .CSV file

Comment: So, save the results of processing file1.csv back into file1.csv?

Comment: No. ADD content form the .JSON files into file.csv. IF the .JSON filename matches a filed in "file1.csv" then PRINT the .JSON file contents in that row

Comment: I'm still unclear. Take some time to edit your question so all the requirements, input and output, are clearly stated.

Comment: Ok I've updated the post with inputs and desired outputs. Sorry bout it hope it makes sense

Comment: my existing answer still produces that output. Do you have `jq` installed?

Comment: Yes I've got jq installed. Maybe I haven't got it setup correctly. Where does the main .csv file need to be located (the one that will have the JSON data added)? And where should my JSON files be? I created a dir called "mediaid" but it keeps saying "No such file or directory"